# Spanish resident to work in the Netherlands

Tags: netherlands, spain, work-permit

I am a Spanish resident (not a Spanish citizen, RESIDENCIA LARGA DURACION) that would like to work for the summer up to 3 months in the Netherlands. Can I do it and what it will be the procedure?

Comment: What kind of work?  I think the procedure will vary, depending.